# Firebase Realtime Database Rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database rules is as below which only lets authorized users to read/write their own data. However, I want everyone to read all database without any authorization. How can I do it?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not 100% clear what you mean  by "I want everyone to read all database without any authorization".

If you mean that anyone should be able to read the posts (even users without an account, i.e. unauthenticated users) you would adapt your rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": true,
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

---

If you mean that only authenticated users should be able to read the posts of all the other users (in others words, authenticated users shall get the authorization to read all posts), you would adapt your rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
       "$uid": {
         ".read": auth != null,
         ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

---

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) for more details.